# How to avoid toggling on "embedded" HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML-Java code:

```
<div id="div_id" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <a id="a_id" href="...">...</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#a_id').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('...');
    });
  </script>
</div>

<div id="details_id" style="display: none;">
  Some text to be displayed!

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div_id').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#details_id').toggle();
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

When (in my browser) I click on the HTML `div#div_id` then it toggles the `div#details_id`. However, the toggling happens also when I click on the HTML `a#a_id`. I would like to implement the behavior so that when I click on the HTML `a#a_id` it doesn't toggle the `div#details_id`.

How can I make that?

Comment: Um... `#a_id` is a part of `#div_id`, so it should be impossible to click on `#a_id` without also clicking on `#div_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the `click` event from triggering both handlers, stop the [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link3) on the `a` element:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Or more concisely:

```
// Your code

return false;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfzU2/2/**

Comment: You need to prevent bubbling for the `a` element not for the div right?

Comment: Right. The `a` is a child of the `div`, so you don't want it to propagate events up to the `div`.

Comment: Why people voted up the @Sidharth Mudgal's answer? Is there some reason to that?

Comment: Its more concise. Both methods work but if you use mine, you wouldn't need `$('#a_id').click(function(event) { alert('...'); return false; });`

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
$('#div_id').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target != $('#a_id')[0]) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#details_id').toggle();
    }
});
```